# How to discern quality of a breakout board? other than proper soldering on back of board

Tags: power-supply, pcie, breakout, gpu

I see three different breakout boards for a project I am doing yet I am not sure which one to pick. How would i know which is of higher quality?

I do see a metal circle inserts in board two and three which I assume are used to hold the plastic six pin plug in place. other than that I am not sure which of these boards would be better in terms of build quality, overall longevity, and performance?

[Board 1](http://www.ebay.com/itm/PARALLEL-MINER-X7-BREAKOUT-BOARD-ADAPTER-24-INCH-16AWG-6-PIN-MALE-TO-8-PIN-6-2/272815452702?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2055119.m1438.l2649):
[Board 2](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/New-6-Pin-Connectors-Breakout-Board_60680486965.html?spm=a2700.8443308.0.0.BvgkqO):
[Board 3](http://holybitcoin.com/product/gekkoscience-dual-purpose-dps800-dps1200hp-common-slot-breakout-board/):

Any input is appreciated as i am completely new to using such boards and do not want to use something that i am sure to screw up just by handling a bit roughly due to my amateur ways.

Also, when choosing cables that go into these. a seller mentioned that he had 16 guage cables that came with 16 gauge power cables and 18 gauge ground cables.  why would this make any sense. Doesn't that lower the wattage ratting for the entire cable at that point to the 18 gauge rating?

*Statement from seller on cables*: Note these are 16 Guage Class Cables / Positive Wires are 16 guage / the 2x Negative Wires are 18 Guage.

Comment: Board 2: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/New-6-Pin-Connectors-Breakout-Board_60680486965.html?spm=a2700.8443308.0.0.BvgkqO

Comment: thanks you Trevor, i was not able to add the third link due to reputation points apparently.

Comment: If you're concerned about quality, the last place you should be thinking about buying from is eBay or equivalent.

Comment: litterally the only place i could find these boards. here is the cheapest looking board i have found. 
for this reason i did not include it.  At least they all look better than this imo: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01N7BWUXQ/ref=s9u_simh_gw_i4?ie=UTF8&fpl=fresh&pd_rd_i=B01N7BWUXQ&pd_rd_r=JMP34MGJHVKWT819HAB1&pd_rd_w=ocz3I&pd_rd_wg=iQ1tk&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=&pf_rd_r=NR1Z95Z3P3BA7A7AH7A3&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=1cf9d009-399c-49e1-901a-7b8786e59436&pf_rd_i=desktop

Comment: eek.. bitcoin... **I feel dirty just clicking the link for #3**... thanks. Really though the only way to know for sure is to order/buy all three and compare them.

Answer (score 2):

> How would i know which is of higher quality?

Quality, in this context, usually means life expectancy and life expectancy is dependant on many factors such as: -

- How the boards have been handled previously
- How the boards were made/soldered
- Component deratings when in use
- How or if the boards were tested during production
- Recommendations about how to properly use the boards

Most of the above comes down to buying from a reputable dealer who, in turn, only handes products that meet certain design and manufacturing standards.

Alibaba or ebay does not reckon on my top 100 list. Why do you think designers of aircraft and missiles etc take such a lot of time working out failure modes and component deratings whilst ensuring that the components bought have a well-defined history through manufacturing and shipping.

Comment: not disagreeing. but i have no idea where to get a quality board. There are no "reputable dealers" to date that manufacture these boards that I am aware of.  i cant design it myself, well maybe i could if there something in autocad that i am not aware of but thats a diff topic. and the other option is to use a standard PSU that powers a desktop pc and that is totally inefficient and not a long term strategy. Everybody beating me up for turning to Ebay which i get but i am not aware of any other option at this point. I just appreciate the input.

Comment: Clint Eastwood as dirty Harry said "ask yourself one question, do you feel lucky?"

Comment: if only this were a time for jokes. and as a matter of fact i do feel lucky.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the board quality, it's hard to tell from the pictures. Soldering quality, flux residue, silkscreen quality..., also mechanical design as the inserts you point out can give clues, but you'll have to take the risk anyway.

As for the gauge thing, maybe there was a bit of misunderstanding here. Checking the 2nd picture from the first link, you can tell all the wires that plug in the board are the same gauge, 16 supposedly. In the 3rd picture you can see the other end of the harness. There are some 'auxiliary' connections with smaller gauge (18 supposedly), which are what the seller means. Note that I say 'auxiliary' because I'm not familiar with this application and don't know what they are for. Depending on the purpose of these, the change in gauge can or can't be a concern (probably not and so not a problem with the harness rating).